# Is a reverse iterator constructed from an iterator is its previous iterator?

Tags: c++, reverse-iterator

On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator it is said:

> `std::reverse_iterator` is an iterator adaptor that reverses the direction of a given iterator. In other words, when provided with a bidirectional iterator, `std::reverse_iterator` produces a new iterator that moves from the end to the beginning of the sequence defined by the underlying bidirectional iterator.
>
> For a reverse iterator `r` constructed from an iterator `i`, the relationship `&*r == &*(i-1)` is always true (as long as `r` is dereferenceable); thus a reverse iterator constructed from a one-past-the-end iterator dereferences to the last element in a sequence.

So I've tried this code to understand more:

```
int main() {


    std::deque<int> di{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 }; // fibonacci series
    // deque has bi-directional iterators

    std::deque<int>::iterator offEnd = di.end(); // one-past the last element in di
    std::deque<int>::reverse_iterator r(offEnd); // constructing a reverse iterator from an iterator from deque<int> di

    std::cout << &offEnd << " : " /*<< *r */ << std::endl;
    std::cout << &(offEnd - 1) << " : " << *(offEnd - 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << &*r << " : " << *r << std::endl;

}
```

The output:

```
0023FDAC :
0023FC9C : 13
0048C608 : 13
```

Why the iterators have the same value but on different addresses???!!!

Does this mean `&*r == &*(i-1)` is not correct?

Comment: What does this `std::cout << &(offEnd - 1) << " : " << *(offEnd - 1) << std::endl;` do then you have the answer?

Comment: Your quote from the linked article is sligthly different. In the link, you'll find `&*r == &*(i-1)`, not what you have in your post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The address are different because you have different objects.  `(offEnd - 1)` and `r` are distinct objects.  Since they are, they have different addresses.  What you need to do is dereference the iterator, and then get that address.  Doing that gives you

```
int main()
{
    std::deque<int> di{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 }; // fibonacci series
    // deque has bi-directional iterators

    std::deque<int>::iterator offEnd = di.end(); // one-past the last element in di
    std::deque<int>::reverse_iterator r(offEnd); // constructing a reverse iterator from an iterator from deque<int> di

    std::cout << &(*offEnd) << " : " /*<< *r */ << std::endl;
    std::cout << &(*(offEnd - 1)) << " : " << *(offEnd - 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << &*r << " : " << *r << std::endl;
}
```

which outputs:

```
0xed3c8c : 
0xed3c88 : 13
0xed3c88 : 13
```

And as you can see the addresses are the same since the iterators point to the same element.

---

Do note that

```
&(*offEnd)
```

is illegal and is undefined behavior.  There is no object at `end()` so it is illegal to dereference the past the end iterator.

Comment: The code crushes on MSVC++14. I think there a UB in this code. Because on GCC it works.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa That could be because of `&(*offEnd)`.  You are not allowed to dereference the end iterator.  Does it crash if you remove `std::cout << &(*offEnd) << " : " /*<< *r */ << std::endl;`?

Comment: Ah yea eaxactly! Now I've removed dereferencing the `offEnd` and it works fine! Thank you!

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Cool.  I've added a note about that into the answer.

Comment: I also made some changes on your code to be able to dereference `offEnd` making it denoting the last element not the past-last element to check the results: `std::deque<int>::iterator it = di.end() - 1; // the last element in di
 std::deque<int>::reverse_iterator r(it);
 std::cout << &(*it) << " : " << *it << std::endl;
 std::cout << &(*(it - 1)) << " : " << *(it - 1) << std::endl;
 std::cout << &*r << " : " << *r << std::endl;` Now it is clear and your code works like a charm. This is the result: `005EC608 : 13
005EC604 : 8
005EC604 : 8`

Comment: Thank you very much! you are always helpful and positive.

Comment: up-vote. only a small addition: The addresses are different since the program is ill-formed here in the OP's topic:   `std::cout << &(offEnd - 1) << " : " << *(offEnd - 1) << std::endl;` because `-` returns an r-value and taking the address of an r-value causes the program to be Ill-Formed.

Comment: @Raindrop7 That is only true for built in types and then it is actually a compiler error.  The only UB was `&(*offEnd)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is clear as you can see also when you are querying the address of `offEnd` and `offEnd-1`, which are the same. You are querying the address of the iterator and this stays the same if you move within this iterator with the `-`-operator.